# Leer tabla .dbf desde PHP

Tags: php

tengo varios días luchando con esto, necesito migran un tabla de `.dbf` a MySQL para lo cual intento abrirla con el siguiente cogido para luego recorrerla pero me arroja un error,

```
$db = dbase_open("INARTICULOS.DBF", 0);

if($db){
    $numero_registros = dbase_numrecords($db);
    for($i = 1; $i <= $numero_registros; $i++){
        $fila = dbase_get_record_with_names($db, $i);

        echo $fila["RAZSOC"];
    }
}
```

> Error: * Fatal error: Call to undefined function dbase_open() in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DBFtoMysql/index.php on line 5*

Se que falta activar la extensión dbase, pero en el archivo `php.ini` no esta, e intentado desde mi Mac y desde Windows ayuda por favor.

Comment: ¿Es necesario que lo hagas con PHP? Conozco maneras mas fáciles de hacer esto sin tener que programar una sola linea de código.

Answer (score 1):

Es necesario comprobar en el directorio de archivos PHP(xampp/php/ext) que **php_gmp.dll** exista y habilitarlo si existe, a continuación, en el php.ini añade esta cadena

> extension = php_gmp.dll

en la sección de extensiones.

Si el archivo no existe descargalo, luego añadelo a PHP - http://www.dll4free.com/php_gmp.dll.html

Solución tomada de SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344867/how-to-solve-call-to-undefined-function-dbase-open-error-in-windows

Comment: Si ya lo hice y el error persiste.

Comment: Te sigue saliendo el mismo o error o uno nuevo?, ¿reiniciaste apache luego de hacer los cambios?

Comment: el mismo error, ya reinicie apache, amigo tengo un pc con windows y otro con Mac y en los dos e echo lo mismo pero sale el mismo error.

Comment: Comprueba que también exista php_dbase.dll

Comment: ok, te comento, en windows no existia ni el archivo ni la linea en php.ini, yo descargue el archivo y agregue la linea pero error persiste.

Answer (score 0):

hace un tiempo tenia un problema igual al habilitar unas extensiones en el archivo php.ini y agregando los dll en la carpeta ext y aun seguía el error. lo solucione descargando otra versión de xampp y verificando que este contenga los dll luego los habilite en php.ini y así resolví mi problema es algo confuso pero me funciono

Comment: hola, cuando te refieres a descargar otra versión de xampp y una anterior? por favor indícame cual.

Comment: cuando tenia mi problema mi xampp era el mas resiente descargue la versión anterior ..